# Sound Supported Remote Desktop Connection to Ubuntu from Mac OS X

Tags: rdp

I created Ubuntu server on DigitalOcean and would like to connect to Ubuntu desktop over Remote Desktop Protocol from Macbook Pro to watch movies and listen to music.

I tried VNC server and clients and they work flawlessly except they do not transfer sound of Ubuntu Desktop over VNC session.

Is it possible to watch and listen of Ubuntu desktop for Remote Desktop? If so, how can I achieve this?